# Api platform Subresource context when attributes have relation on the same entity

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I develop a new api with api-platform/core@2.6.6 and I have a problem with my subresource.

I have 2 Entities Project and User:

```
 // App\Entity\Project
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="managedProjects")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 * @Groups({"project:read", "project:write"})
 */
#[ApiSubresource(
    maxDepth: 1,
)]
private User $manager;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="projects", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
 * @Groups({"project:read", "project:write"})
 */
#[ApiSubresource(
    maxDepth: 1,
)]
private Collection $developers;
```

On ApiDoc I can see the subresource url :

- /api/projects/{id}/manager
- /api/projects/{id}/developers

But when I call /api/projects/{id}/developers the request body contains:

```
{
   "@context": "/api/contexts/User",
   "@id": "/api/projects/2/manager",
   "@type": "hydra:Collection",
   "hydra:member": [//...]
}
```

In the response you can see @id is not good. When I remove the @ApiSubresource on $manager, all works fine.

Any idea?

Thanks for all and happy new year!

Comment: What do you mean by '@id is not good' ? can you specify what is the expected result ?

Comment: For me the response should be "@id": "/api/projects/2/developers".

Comment: Did you tried without  `fetch="EXTRA_LAZY"` ?